# Configuring Windows Server 2008R2 to give preference to administrator remote sessions

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, iis

We have had a few times recently when problems with an IIS web application have consumed server resources causing the server to become unresponsive.  What has made this problem worse is that is that trying to remote into the server (e.g. to use task manager to kill any rogue IIS worker processes) has been near impossible because the server is not giving the remote session sufficient priority over the other processes.  Is there a way to give make sure that Windows Server 2008 R2 gives precedence to remote sessions (or processes started by administrators) over server processes (e.g. IIS worker processes)?

It appears that [WSRM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/05/29/using-wsrm-to-control-rds-dynamic-fair-share-scheduling.aspx?Redirected=true) might be related to my problem.  However the documentation is hard to decipher as the use cases seem to center on giving one remote session priority over another or giving one IIS worker process priority over another.  Giving remote sessions priority over worker processes does not seem to be covered, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Don't believe that is possible on the server level, you would instead limit your web application resource limits to ensure for example its CPU limit doesn't exceed 75% or 500 MB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I've been able to do before with this situation is have a program such as Prio http://www.prnwatch.com/prio/ to set the IIS worker to say 3 cores out of 4 so it can only max 100% on 3 of 4 cores of a multicored CPU. However if its maxing out memory its a different story!

Comment: http://www.bill2-software.com/processmanager/index.shtml another one if Prio is not quite powerful enough.